# error: cannot borrow ... as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, mutability

I've instantiated a struct `result` and pass it as `mutable ref` to another function, that fills this struct with data.

AFTER that, I pass this struct as `immutable ref` to other functions, to insert the data into a database.

```
let mut result = indexer::IndexRefreshResultHolder {
            putlist: Vec::new(),
            dellist: Vec::new(),
        };

indexer::refresh_indeces(&mut new_idx_set, old_idx_set_opt, &mut result);

pg::delete_index_rows(&mut tx, &result.dellist).await?;
pg::insert_index_rows(&mut tx, &result.putlist).await?;
```

Signature of refresh_indeces is like below:

```
pub fn refresh_indeces<'a>(
    new_idx: &'a mut IndexSet,
    old_idx_opt: Option<&'a mut IndexSet>,
    result: &'a mut IndexRefreshResultHolder<'a>,
) -> Result<(), AppError>
```

The function takes data from `new_idx` and `old_idx` and merges it into `result`.

Compiler error:
`cannot borrow 'result.dellist' as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable`. Same for 'result.putlist'.

I understand that since the struct was `mutable borrowed` to `refresh_indeces` it can not be made sure, that data changes afterwards.

My question now is: "How can I make the compiler understand, that `result` is not changed after `refresh_indeces` was called" or in other words: "How can `result` passed as `immutable ref` again after it was passed once as `mutable ref`?

Thanks for you help.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf553982fb9b2dca6eb33816da749e8d)

Comment: I very much doubt that all the lifetimes in `refresh_indeces` should be the same…

Comment: Why not? The content of result is constructed from new_idx and old_idx and I use refrences. That's why I coupled the lifetimes. Is this a mistake in thinking?

Comment: `&'a Foo<'a>` is almost always a mistake. Since you haven't given the source for `refresh_indeces` it's hard to say if this is the case here, but I suspect that this is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a new scope so the `&mut` is dropped before the other refs need to be used:

```rust
let mut result = indexer::IndexRefreshResultHolder {
    putlist: Vec::new(),
    dellist: Vec::new(),
};
{
    indexer::refresh_indeces(&mut new_idx_set, old_idx_set_opt, &mut result);
}
pg::delete_index_rows(&mut tx, &result.dellist).await?;
pg::insert_index_rows(&mut tx, &result.putlist).await?;
```

EDIT: Actually your lifetimes are wrong, since they are enforcing to extend a lifetime for the `&mut`. You can separate them:

```rust
fn refresh_indeces<'a, 'b, 'c>(
    new_idx: &'a mut IndexSet,
    old_idx_opt: Option<&'a mut IndexSet>,
    result: &'b mut IndexRefreshResultHolder<'a>,
) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
```

[Playground](http://%20fn%20refresh_indeces%3C%27a,%20%27b,%20%27c%3E(%20%20%20%20%20new_idx:%20&%27a%20mut%20IndexSet,%20%20%20%20%20old_idx_opt:%20Option%3C&%27b%20mut%20IndexSet%3E,%20%20%20%20%20result:%20&%27c%20mut%20IndexRefreshResultHolder%3C%27a%3E,%20)%20-%3E%20Result%3C(),%20std::io::Error%3E%20%7B)

Also, you are creating some temporary references in your playground that will need fixing. And after that another bunch of fixes about ownership will come too

Comment: I also thouht, that this might help, but no it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MarkoSeidenglanz, could you then add a bit more context. We are missing something in the question I think.

Comment: I've created a playground link within my first post. Please have a look at first function `main`

Answer (score -1):

Resolved it by replacing slicing:

```
result.dellist.extend(old_idx.rows[i_old..].to_vec().iter());
```

with an iterator:

```
for row in old_idx.rows.iter().skip(i_old) {
    result.dellist.push(row);
}
```